# I want to list down those months in 1990 when more than 2 employees were born

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, group-by

Following query executes successfully but it is not giving result

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'fm MONTH'), COUNT(DATE_OF_BIRTH) "NOS"
    FROM EMP 
GROUP BY DATE_OF_BIRTH 
  HAVING DATE_OF_BIRTH <= TO_DATE('31-12-1990','DD-MM-YYYY')
         AND DATE_OF_BIRTH >= TO_DATE('01-01-1990','DD-MM-YYYY')
         AND COUNT(DATE_OF_BIRTH) >= 2
```

Comment: If this is homework btw, you should have a read [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your desired date range out of the `HAVING` clause and into a `WHERE` clause.
Also, if you want to group everyone together by the month they were born, rather than their individual birthdays, you'll need to `GROUP BY` the month, rather than the DATE_OF_BIRTH.

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'fm MONTH')"Month", COUNT(TO_CHAR(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'fm MONTH'))"NoS"
    FROM EMP
   WHERE DATE_OF_BIRTH <= TO_DATE('31-12-1990','DD-MM-YYYY') AND DATE_OF_BIRTH >= TO_DATE('01-01-1990','DD-MM-YYYY')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'fm MONTH') 
  HAVING COUNT(TO_CHAR(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'fm MONTH')) >= 2
```